# BASH - Why does TEST=' .* ' assign the listing of the current directory to TEST?

Tags: bash

This is driving me nuts. Everything in single quotes is supposed to be assigned as is, yet  if I do the following:

TEST=' .* '

echo $TEST

I get a bunch of garbage on the screen listing all "dot" files in the current directory...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
echo "$TEST"
```

If you don't quote the variable, it is expanded on the second command line.

Answer (score 1):

It actually assigns ".*" to TEST. It only expands to the file listing when you echo it.